# Custom Create Maps in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, texture, procedural-generation

I am trying to create some procedurally created terrains for which i need to create noise maps. How do I create a texture of noise map in OpenGL and then pass that in my vertex shader as a heightMap? 
I know the algorithms to create noises, like Perlin or Simplex, but no idea how to put this data into a texture.

Comment: "*no idea how to put this data into a texture.*" Um, why not? It's just bytes that represent values.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on what exactly you are struggling with (maybe some code examples). Assuming you know how to create the noise field and how to upload and use a texture in OpenGL, then it is hard to tell what your problem is since it is not really that difficult.